# How to add existent database into my app in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite

I have to add an existent DB into my iphone app
I' ve tried to put it into the project's folder and used this init function

```
-(id) initDatabase{
    databaseName = @"mydatabase.sqlite";
    // Get the path to the documents directory and append the databaseName
 NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
 databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
 [databasePath retain];

    return self;
}
```

and then i used this function

```
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK){ //inserting methods
```

but I have an error: the table 'nametable' does not exists, I am sure that this table exists and I think that these methods create a new db file into the device path.

Comment: I've tried pathForResource:ofType: but it retun null, not a path..do you know why? edit: I know why it is null:I HAVE TO CALL INITDATABASE FUNCTION! how I could call initDatabse function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have any files in the documents folder to start. Everything that comes with the app has to be included in the app bundle. The first time the app runs, the documents folder is always empty.

You need to locate the file inside the app bundle using NSBundle's `pathForResource:ofType:`.

If the DB is readonly, you can just leave it there. If it is readwrite, you need to copy the file into the documents or library folder the first time the app launches.

---

**Update:**

> could you make an example about using
>   'NSBundle's pathForResource:ofType:'
>   please?I'm sorry but I'm new to iphone
>   sdk

It's just:

```
NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myDatabase" ofType:@"sqlite"];
```

Comment: could you make an example about using 'NSBundle's pathForResource:ofType:' please?I'm sorry but I'm new to iphone sdk.

Answer (score 0):

In the sidebar, check *"Targets" => (Your Target) => "Copy Bundle Resources"*. I think your database file might not have been copied because Xcode has no idea what file type that is.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I checked "copy bundle resources" and there I have mydatabase.sqlite..I also opened it with sqlite manager and I have my table, I also checked the path created ("databasepath"): me/library/applicationsupport/IPhone simulator/ecc ecc/documents/ and there is mydatabase.sqlite BUT IS EMPTY!!! maybe this is created  by the methods but I want to use MY db not a new db! how could I fix that?